# Dividing between values in an Excel pivot table

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2019

I am attempting to use a pivot table to sort numerical values by month and year (the field 'Close/Last'), and wish run calculations that take the standard deviation of the 'Close/Last' data for each month, and then divide by the mean of the 'Close/Last' data for that month. My pivot table looks like this:

[image]

And my fields:

[image]

I define the formula in "Field 1" as follows:

[image]

But for some reason, as you can see in the first image, this field results in a divide by zero error. I have not been able to diagnose the problem and any guidance as to how to correct it would be much appreciated. I am using MS Excel 2019.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new measure via Excel Power BI maybe helpful, but it sadly doesn't support Mac devices.

I suggest you use [GETPIVOTDATA function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/getpivotdata-function-8c083b99-a922-4ca0-af5e-3af55960761f) to get the data of "StdDev Close/Last" and "Average of Close/Last". Then use formula to get the results that you need.

- First, my field list is as following.

[image]

- Then the GETPIVOTDATA formulas are as following.

**For 2019**, the formula to get "StdDev Close/Last" is `=getpivotdata("StdDev Close/Last",$E$3,"Date",$E6,"Years",$F$4)`.

[image]

The formula to get "Average of Close/Last" is `=getpivotdata("Average of Close/Last",$E$3,"Date",$E6,"Years",$F$4)`.

[image]

**For 2020**, the formula to get "StdDev Close/Last" is `=getpivotdata("StdDev Close/Last",$E$3,"Date",$E6,"Years",$H$4)`.

The formula to get "Average of Close/Last" is `=getpivotdata("Average of Close/Last",$E$3,"Date",$E6,"Years",$H$4)`.

- Enter the formulas beside with the pivottable, `=if(or(F25=0,F25=""),"",E25/F25)`, `=if(or(I25=0,I25=""),"",H25/I25)`.

[image]